# Regex Help: Subfolder/FilePath.extension

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Regexs are my nemesis :(
Please help with the following:

```
If the domain contains <string>
For all links with a .pdf extension
redirect to /Docs/<pdfPath>
```

So for example:

> example.pdf -> /Docs/example.pdf

and

> /app/example.pdf -> /Docs/app/example.pdf

I currently have the following (after much trawling on SO) which is working only for filenames (not subfolder paths).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} domainString
RewriteRule ^([^./]+\.pdf)$ /Docs/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite rules should be

```
RewriteRule ^\/?([^.]+\.pdf)$ /Docs/$1 [L,NC]
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW6iD4/4)**

Comment: This works! Thank you! Will accept once the SO timeout has passed.

Comment: @starkeen: Corrected the regex.

Comment: @noob the error was caused by the initial expression, before the edit to include .pdf. Working now!

Comment: I missed the fact that `.` should not be the part of URI except the extension of file. Corrected now.